# Dynamics 365 online issue with Email Synchronization (SSS)

Tags: dynamics-crm, exchange-server, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365, server-side-sync

in my organization we have a mailbox that receives email from different sources (about 5) everyday, set to track all incoming emails in the CRM.

All the mails are correctly tracked on the CRM every day, except for one that always fails (same source, similar content every day).

If I send the exact same email from another address, the mail is correctly synchronized with the CRM, so I think it could be something related with Exchange.

This is the message I get if I open the mailbox record:

```
    An unknown error occurred while receiving email through the mailbox "xxxxxx". 
The owner of the associated email server profile xxxxx has been notified. The system will try to receive email again later.

    Email Server Error Code: Exchange server returned UnknownIncomingEmailIntegrationError -2147220970 exception
```

Looking for this specific message didn't get me any result, while just searching the error code I found out it could be something related to plugins.
Unfortunately there is no plugin that fires on email creation, same for workflows and so on. By the way, sending the email from another address just works fine.
Has anyone ever had such a problem? Is there some place where I can find other logs and dig deeper in the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you already checked out this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4052842 ? SSS is riddled with issues recently...

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your comment. The error seems similar, but the error code is different and I'm using OWA (Outlook Web App). By the way I tried with EWS editor with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else experiencing this issue: I received the error code `-2147218683`, which is different, but it turns out this was due to the user in question not having the right security role. Gave the account sys admin and the error went away.